# What is the best way to understand the internals of execve in linux?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, exec

I tried looking into the source code of `fs/exec.c` (linux kernel code). However, I am not able to understand it line by line. Any suggestions on how should I approach to have a good understanding? Any resources to throw light on the same?

Comment: From what point of view do you want to understand it? From inside the kernel, or from application (user-land) programs? Do you understand well what syscalls are? What processes are? What virtual memory and process address space means?

Comment: Basically I am trying to read the source code and unable to understand it.So I am looking for some kind of resources that can help me in understanding it.

Comment: Why do you read the source code? From an application point of view, a system call (such as `execve`) is an elementary atomic operation. For resources, read a good book on Advanced Unix programming, then read a good book on Linux kernel internals.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read the sub-chapter named as "The exec-like Functions" in the book "Understanding Linux Kernel". In the first edition, it is sub-chapter 19.4.